# Its showing 'str' is not callable, how to be able to create loops

Tags: error-handling

I'm pretty new at this and I'm kinda experimenting with loops. I was wondering what I am doing wrong with this? and what can I do to fix it? Would I have to try another tactic? Please let me know! It is showing that str is not callable, but I do not know what that means?

```
def get_burger_choice():
        burger_choice = input("Which one would you like? cheesy, regular, or veggie: ")
        return burger_choice

def price_burger(burger_choice, burger_price):
    if burger_choice == 'cheesy':
        burger_price = 3.00
    elif burger_choice == 'regular':
        burger_price = 2.00
    elif burger_choice == 'veggie':
        burger_price = 2.00
    else:
        print("we do not have that, sorry")
    return burger_price

def total_price(burger_price, burger_choice=None):
    print("Your total is $", burger_price)


def closing(burger_choice):
    if burger_choice == 'cheesy':
        print("Nice selection, you've picked our best!")
    else:
        print("thank you")



def tryagain(main):
  tryagain = input("\nWould you like to try again? yes or no: ")
  if tryagain == 'yes':
      main()
  elif tryagain == 'no':
      print("\n------------End---------------")
  else:
      oncemore(tryagain)
      
def oncemore(tryagain):
    oncemore = input("\nWould you like to try again? yes or no: ")
    if tryagain == 'yes':
      main()
    elif tryagain == 'no':
        print("\n------------End---------------")
    else:
      tryagain(main)
      
def main(burger_price=0):
  burger_choice = get_burger_choice()
  burger_price = price_burger(burger_choice,burger_price)
  total_price(burger_price)
  closing(burger_choice)
  tryagain(main)
  oncemore(tryagain)

main()
```

Comment: Can you add the complete error message in the question. It would be helpful to understand

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 49, in main
    tryagain(main)
  File "main.py", line 33, in tryagain
    oncemore(tryagain)
  File "main.py", line 42, in oncemore
    tryagain(main)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: This is the error it is showing

Comment: Got it. Solution coming in a min

Comment: Did the below solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The issue start from the function. Here you have a function tryagain but as soon as you are entering you are entering you are creating a new varian;e of same name. Now, that in itself will not cause any issue. But, you are passing that variable to `oncemore` which is a string

```py
def tryagain(main):
  tryagain = input("\nWould you like to try again? yes or no: ")
  if tryagain == 'yes':
      main()
  elif tryagain == 'no':
      print("\n------------End---------------")
  else:
      oncemore(tryagain)
```

Let's look into oncemore function. In this function you are calling tryagain which is string. Hence, the error which is string is not callable.

```py
def oncemore(tryagain):
    oncemore = input("\nWould you like to try again? yes or no: ")
    if tryagain == 'yes':
      main()
    elif tryagain == 'no':
        print("\n------------End---------------")
    else:
      tryagain(main)
```

Solution:
Rename your variables and don't pass function as parameters. That is not needed in your case. All function can access all other function which is present in your file.

PS: You can change your main function to below code to make it more readable

```py
def main():
  
  choice = "yes"
  while choice is not "no":
    burger_choice = get_burger_choice()
    burger_price = price_burger(burger_choice,burger_price)
    total_price(burger_price)
    closing(burger_choice)
    choice = input("\nWould you like to try again? yes or no: ")
```